# R-ggplot2: geom_abline doesn't flip with scale_y_reverse

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting lake data in ggplot2 with a statistical trendline, using `geom_abline()` and the slope and intercept calculated by the trend function. One of the parameters I'm plotting is traditionally shown with a reversed y-axis (it's Secchi depth, so reversing the y-axis mimics looking down into the water and shows deeper depths lower on the graph).

Adding `scale_y_reverse()` to the plot doesn't reverse the abline as well. I've worked around this with some if-then-else to pass in -slope and -intercept when the axis gets reversed, but it feels like a clumsy hack. Reversing the y-axis should reverse everything based on the y-axis, which includes ablines, hlines, etc. as well as data. Does anyone have a more elegant solution?

Here's a bit of reproducible code using the mtcars dataset. When the scale is reversed, the blue line is still drawn with a positive slope and intercept, so it's no longer on the graph. I can draw in a red line with -slope and -intercept.

```
data(mtcars)

p<-ggplot(data=mtcars,aes(x=mpg,y=disp))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_abline(slope=12,intercept=100,color="blue")

p

p+scale_y_reverse()

p+scale_y_reverse()+
  geom_abline(slope=-12,intercept=-100,color="red")
```

(I'd also appreciate some input on whether you think this is a bug worth posting to the ggplot2 developers, or if you think the existing behavior is way to draw on a reversed axis -- and why.)

Comment: Try putting the scale_y_reverse() layer after the geom_abline() layer. ggplot builds graphs one layer at a time, and the ordering of the layers makes a difference.

Comment: Nevermind, that does not work.  This issue discusses why reference lines are not affected by scales by design: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/46